# logical comparison operator

Tags: c++, oop, function, error-handling, operator-overloading

Here is my code for my logical comparison operator (==) overloaded. I use this to check if two strings are identical in size and content. It should return false otherwise.

```
 bool MyString::operator==(const MyString& other)const
 {
    if(other.Size == this->Size)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this->Size+1; i++)
        {
            if(&other == this)                          
                  return true;            
        }
    }
    else
        return false;
 }
```

When I ran valgrind it told me warning control reaches end of non-void function. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue and what I could do to better the code?

Comment: The loop appears to not compare the content of the object, just repeatedly checks if the address of `other` and `this` are the same.

Comment: hmm I didn't even realize that, thank you. Is the size comparison at least right? I'm a little shaky with this.

Comment: Probably not. If you have an array equivalent to `char s[Size]` then it is incorrect as array indexes start at 0, meaning the last valid index is `Size - 1`.

Comment: What happens if it enters the first if, and then either doesn't enter the loop of enter the loop and the inside condition is never true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When control reaches the end of your `for` loop, you immediately get to the end of the function without returning a value.

It looks to me like you have the logic in your `for` loop munged anyway -- it's comparing the address of the other item to this. While it's sort of okay to do that, you only need to do it once, not in a loop.

In the loop, you undoubtedly want to compare the characters in the string, not the addresses of the objects.

Edit:

A typical implementation would be something on this general order:

```
class MyString { 
    char *data;
    size_t length;
public:
    // ...
    bool operator==(MyString const &other) const {
        if (length != other.length)
            return false;
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
            if (data[i] != other.data[i]) // If we see any inequality
                return false;             //     they're not equal
        return true;                      // all equal, so the strings are equal.
    }
};
```

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I want to do. The only thing is I'm unsure of how to do that in the simplest way.

Comment: Thank you for that! Makes much sense!

Answer (score 1):

It's not too clear what determines equality if the sizes are equal, but
the loop suggests that you're looking for something like:

```
bool
MyString::operator==( MyString const& other ) const
{
    return size == other.size && std::equals( ??? );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, if you enter the `for` loop, and the condition `&other == this` will not be met, you will never return anything. To fix this, you should just remove the `else` statement. This will cause your function to return false either if the  `other.Size == this->Size` condition is not met, or if you've gone through the whole loop, and have not used `return` inside of it.

The second problem is the line `if(&other == this)`. I believe that inside of the loop you intend to check all the symbols of the strings. But now you are only checking the pointer to the class itself. To check the characters, you will need to use something like `if( other->data == this->data )`, provided you have a `data` member in which you store the...data (sorry for tautology).

Another little flow is in the design. You see, to check that the strings *are* equal, you need to look through each and every character and check that they match. However, to prove the strings are *not* equal, you need to find just 1 pair of characters that does not match. After that, it is pointless to continue comparing. So it is better to changee your condition in the cycle to a negative one, in order to stop comparing immediately after you fuond a pair that does not match, and not to do useless comparations of other characters.

Generaly, it is a good practice to return all the errors as fast as it's possible and avoid unneeded cumputation. So if you can check something in the begining of your function with a simple check, better do it.

So, after all, you should have something like this:

```
bool MyString::operator==(const MyString& other)const
{
   if(other.Size != this->Size)
       return false;//If the sizes do not match, no need to check anything else. Just return false.

   //If we are here, the sizes match. Lets check the characters.
   for(int i = 0; i < this->Size+1; i++)
   {
       //If some pair doesnt match, the strings are not equal, and we exit.
       if( other->data[i] != this->data[i])                          
                  return false;
   }

   //If we are here, all the characters did match, so we return true.
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm guessing that data would have to be allocated in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the `else`. This way there is a "default" behaviour returning `false` if the condition is not met. It's the functionality you intend, and the compiler or syntax checker won't complain.